# Moving b2Body between b2Worlds

Tags: c++, box2d

I have multiple instances of b2World class (Box2D). How can I move one b2Body from one world to another, while keeping all the params (position/orientation/speed)?

I can create new b2Body in the new world, manually assign positions, velocities, fixtures and joints, and remove it from the first world, but I'm looking for something simpler.

Comment: You're assuming we all know what a b2World class is

Comment: I assumed that tagging this question as "box2d" will be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in Box2D to move bodies between worlds besides doing it the way you've described: copy the related info to the new world, delete the body from the old world. And from what I remember, even that's not going to get you things like the remaining time before the body should sleep. It may well be close enough though for most purposes.

You can also look on the Box2D forum about this. [Transfer or copy full bodies+fixtures between b2Worlds?](http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10169) was asked about back in 2016. It has no responses.

Comment: Oh, I didn't find that one, maybe because it has no answers. Let's hope one day we'll get a function for moving objects between worlds.